# React Native Gesture Handler(ScrollView) not Working

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, react-native-gesture-handler, react-google-autocomplete

Error: NativeViewGestureHandler must be used as a descendant of GestureHandlerRootView. Otherwise the gestures will not be recognized. See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation for more details.

Any Solution for this?

I have tried many methods but no use...
Looking forward some relatable answers...

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap with GestureHandlerRootView

```
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>
            {/* Your entire application components */}
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
}
```